# Multilanguage sub-domain. How to implement?

Tags: php, codeigniter, subdomain, multilingual

I have a requirement that is when the user changes the language except English it needs to show up in the URL as a sub-domain. Example:

English site = www.abc.com
Spanish site (US spanish) = esp-us.abc.com
Spanish site (Spanish spanish) = esp-es.abc.com

How to implement this? I am using code ignitor php. I have a table called `L_languages` which is the language lookup table. It has two columns: one for the language code (esp) and another column for the country code (us) so I can pull this from the database according to the user's language.

But how to write it to the sub-domain and make this process fully database driven so tomorrow if I add a new language the subdomain will work?

- Site is running Apache on CentOS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can have HTACCESS perform a `mod_rewrite` rule identify these instances, or you can apply a blanket rule within HTACCESS and then have PHP do the heavy lifting from there. Or a combination of the two.

### HTACCESS mod_rewrite Solution

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.)?abc.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).abc.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?lang=%1 [QSA,L]
```

Examples using this rule:

```
No Change - These are assumed as the Base
http://www.abc.com
  ==> http://www.abc.com
http://abc.com
  ==> http://abc.com
Language Coded Subdomains
http://de.abc.com
  ==> http://de.abc.com/?lang=de
http://esp-es.abc.com
  ==> http://esp-es.abc.com/?lang=esp-es
Language Coded Subdomains with filename & query
http://esp-us.abc.com/filename.htm
  ==> http://esp.us.abc.com/filename.htm?lang=esp-us
http://fr.abc.com/filename.htm?name=value
  ==> http://fr.abc.com/filename.htm?lang=fr&name=value
```

### PHP Solution

Include this code somewhere towards the top of the page (before language-specific content is generated).

```
<?php
$lang = false;
if( preg_match( '/^(.+)\.abc.com$/' , $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] , $matches )
    && count( $matches )==2
    && $matches[1]!='www' ){
  $lang = $matches[1];
}
```

You can then use the `$lang` variable (which will be `false` if either A) no subdomain, or B) the "www" subdomain is used.
Additionally, you can check the value of the `$lang` variable against an array of acceptable languages, and, if it is not present, again, reset it to false.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP to serve different languages, but if you want those subdomains to work, you'll need to configure your webserver (Apache,IIS, etc.) to setup those subdomains. You'll want to add your webserver of choice to your question. :)

Comment: Site is still not launched so dont have a final webserver of choice but i assume it will be apache running on CentOS which is what my dev enviornment is running.

Comment: OK, well you still have to get that configured. Than you can use $_SERVER http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php to figure out what language the user wants.